# populate textbox on different forms

Tags: vba, excel

I have a listbox and a textbox on userform1.

I am using this code:

```
Me.TextBox10.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:AM100"), 6, False)
```

This works perfectly on userform1, however, I have now also created userform2 but the textbox doesn't populate. Why isn't this code working to populate the textbox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: too little data so I'd throw a guessing: check for actual textbox and listbox names in userform2 be properly referenced in your code

Comment: What makes you think that it doesn't work with UserForm2? How are you initializing / populating UserForm1 and how do you go about these with UserForm2? Please post all relevant VBA code here. Otherwise we cannot help you. For more information please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: wild guess , maybe you havnt named the textbox in userform2 as textbox10 ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - The code I gave in my example definitely works when the text box is on the same userform as the listbox - once the textbox is on a different userform it shows an error 'method or data member not found'

Comment: As other have said, the name for your textbox in userform2 is most likely not referenced properly. You can see why this should be the case by [looking at Microsoft's definition of the error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251375.aspx) you are getting.

Comment: I have managed to get it working. I change the first part of the code:

userform2.TextBox10.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:AM100"), 6, False)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with this slight change:

```
userform2.TextBox10.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ListBox1.Value, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:AM100"), 6, False)
```